# npm install that loads dependency with package.json as authored

Tags: json, node.js, npm, package

I noticed that when viewing a `package.json` under `node_modules`, I see JSON that looks like:

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      "example@0.2.0",
      "C:\\path\\to\\project\\folder"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "example@0.2.0",
  "_id": "example@0.2.0",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_installable": true,
  "_location": "/example",
  "_nodeVersion": "6.2.0",
  "_npmUser": {},
  "_npmVersion": "3.8.9",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "name": "example",
    "raw": "example@0.2.0",
    "rawSpec": "0.2.0",
    "scope": "@edf",
    "spec": "0.2.0",
    "type": "version"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "/"
  ],
  "_resolved": "http://internal.registry/example/-/example-0.2.0.tgz",
  "_shasum": "b564b263db925ff3a8bffdc922c16f8e4b6f4641",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "example@0.2.0",
  "_where": "C:\\path\\to\\project\\folder",
  "author": {
    "name": "NPM User"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "description": "Example Package",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "b564b263db925ff3a8bffdc922c16f8e4b6f4641",
    "tarball": "http://internal.registry/example/-/example-0.2.0.tgz"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "name": "example",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "readmeFilename": "README.md",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "gulp"
  },
  "version": "0.2.0"
}
```

Instead of just:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "description": "Example Package",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "gulp"
  },
  "author": "NPM User",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Is there a command-line argument I can specify to keep dependency `package.json` files as authored when installing, or is there another way I can access the file as authored when there is no repository specified for the package?

I found an option called [`proprietary-attribs`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#proprietary-attribs) on the [`npm-config` documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config) but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: afaik, i don t think you can do that, npm will transform and save the package json file when the new version is created. It won t keep the original package file. The proprietary-attributes, i suspect, are about the tar processing, not anything to npm itself.

Comment: @mh-cbon will npm overwrite those properties if a new version of the package is published without updating the `_` prefixed attributes?

Comment: the values are likely to change between two versions, i d assume so. Note that those underscored values are controlled by npm, not the maintainer. Note also that you are showing values of an installed package which i believe are different from those saved into the tarball stored on npmregistry. And they will be different for different user/os etc (see 1st args, this is windows path). If that helps, you may want to check metadatas of an existing package like [this](https://registry.npmjs.org/@mh-cbon%2faghfabsowecwn) for example.

Comment: @mh-cbon thanks! Requesting the metadata from the registry directly would be a reasonable solution. If you could post that as an answer, I'll upvote and accept.